# why urlopen timeout in eventlet spawn function

Tags: timeout, urlopen, eventlet

I met a  strange question: 

eventlet.green.urllib2.urlopen() raise HTTP Error 408: Request Timeout.

but successfully if open the "# eventlet.green.time.sleep(0.1)"

do anybody know why? thanks a lot!

test.py:

```
import eventlet
import eventlet.green.urllib2

pool = eventlet.GreenPool()
status = "idling"

url_list = [
   "http://192.168.1.218:1995/api/v1/srs_conf", # valid url
   "http://192.168.1.163:1995/api/v1/srs_conf", # valid url
   "http://safsawegdffsd:1995/api/v1/srs_conf", # invalid urls followed
   "http://sddsadfggdfsd:1995/api/v1/srs_conf",
   "http://safsadffddfsd:1995/api/v1/srs_conf",
   "http://safsssadffdsd:1995/api/v1/srs_conf",
   "http://sarsadfggdfsd:1995/api/v1/srs_conf",
   "http://werweer3fsfgv:1995/api/v1/srs_conf"
]

def do_get(url):
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = eventlet.green.urllib2.urlopen(url)
        res = conn.read()
        print res
    except Exception, ex:
        print url, ex
    finally:
        if conn:
            conn.close()

def start():
    for i in range(len(url_list)):
        pool.spawn_n(do_get, url_list[i])
        # eventlet.green.time.sleep(0.1)

while True:
    if status == "idling":
        status = "running"
        start()
    eventlet.green.time.sleep(1)
```

result:

```
http://safsadffddfsd:1995/api/v1/srs_conf <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>
http://sddsadfggdfsd:1995/api/v1/srs_conf <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>
http://safsssadffdsd:1995/api/v1/srs_conf <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>
http://safsawegdffsd:1995/api/v1/srs_conf <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>
http://sarsadfggdfsd:1995/api/v1/srs_conf <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>
http://werweer3fsfgv:1995/api/v1/srs_conf <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>
http://192.168.1.218:1995/api/v1/srs_conf <urlopen error [Errno 10061] WSAECONNREFUSED>
http://192.168.1.163:1995/api/v1/srs_conf HTTP Error 408: Request Timeout
```

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

```
while True:
  if status == "idling":
    status = "running"
    start()
  eventlet.sleep(0)  # or pool.waitall()
```

### Why

Here's what happens:

```
1: while True:               # True, next
2:   if status == "idling":  # True, execute if branch
3:     status = "running"    # set, next
4:     start()               # pool.spawn() N times
                             # go to 1, True, next
2:   if status == "idling":  # False, skip if branch
                             # go to 1, True, next
2:   if status == "idling":  # and again ...
```

There is no point where Python interpreter could enter Eventlet hub and switch to green threads to do network IO.

Eventlet provides cooperative multithreading. Which means you need to yield control to give coroutines chance to run. To yield control, use `eventlet.sleep()`, `GreenPool.waitall()` or wait for any IO, like urlopen `conn.read`.

### Proper way

Remove `while True` loop, Eventlet already has a hidden one for you. Remove `status`.

```
def start():
  # ...

start()
pool.waitall()
```